# Scope of Static variables in Android

Tags: android, performance

In my Android application there are some Boolean variables which I want to access anywhere in the app, by declaring them as public static boolean I can access anywhere but when keeping my app long time in background or if the user clears the memory(by clean master app) then my static variables get reset and again if the user goes to the app from stack then there will be an issue since all my variables got reset to default values.
Instead I am planning to store those boolean vars to Sharedprefs, everytime when I want I will access them from sharedprefs. Everytime reading from sahredprefs is the best way or not?does it effect any performance if I had large number of booleans? Can anyone suggest me what would be the best way of handling this situation.

Answer (score 0):

[SharedPreferences](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html) is the way to go.

Variables saved to SharedPreferences are saved in an xml file. I never had problems in terms of performance when it comes to large set of preferences. I think you should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

SharedPreferences are in fact an XML, they are fast for few values and you can load/save them on the OnPause/OnResume events on the Application class.

If you need to store large amount of data consider using JSON or even better an ORM like SugarORM (greenDAO is good too).